# Out of memory, Mysql_query() unable to save resultset

Tags: php, mysql, memory

I try to load about 30.000 record to mysql select. than i get this warning.
and than i try to break them into smaller limit. Every 1000. but why i still get this warning?

this is my code  :

```
function processDataDb()
{
    $rowIncrement = 1000;

    $query = "SELECT count( * ) as totalfield FROM `isc_xml_data` ";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die ("$query" . mysql_error());

    if ($result) 
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $total_row = $row['totalfield'];

        for($i = 0; $i < $total_row ; $i+=$rowIncrement)
        {
            $sql_c = "SELECT * FROM isc_xml_data order by id LIMIT " . $i . " , " . ($i + $rowIncrement - 1);
            $res_c = mysql_query($sql_c) or die (mysql_error());

            while($row = mysql_fetch_object($res_c)) 
            {
                echo $row->id."\n";
                $this->insertAndUpdateProduct($row->xmldata);       
            }

            unset($res_c);
        }

    } else {
        echo "result is unavailable";
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I guess you don't release memory in `$this->insertAndUpdateProduct($row->xmldata);`; So no matter if you load all records at once or incrementally, they still end all up in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql_c = "SELECT * FROM isc_xml_data order by id LIMIT " .
    $i . " , " . ($i + $rowIncrement - 1);
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html#id714605

The second argument to `LIMIT` is how many you want, not the upper bound; try just `$rowIncrement`.

Comment: omg, how can i forget this. thanks! i will try with new condition.

Answer (score 0):

`unset($res_c);` It's not valid, there is `mysql_free_result($res_c)` function for this.
Also, you can do it without first query with `count(*)` - just make your cycle queries until at least one row returned.

Answer (score 0):

Because of this line:

```
$this->insertAndUpdateProduct($row->xmldata);
```

it's your **XML processing** being very inefficient memory-wise,
while mysql consumes no more than only one row contents.